# %username% variable in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd

I'd like to be able to pass the username variable to a cmd command in a batch script so I can see if the current user is an administrator. I tried this code `start cmd.exe /c "net user %username% > priv.txt"`  It doesn't want to work though, whats the problem and is there a better way to do this? Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: `start` considers the first set of quotes it finds (regardless of where it is in the command) to be the title of the window. Use `start "" cmd.exe /c "net user %username% >priv.txt"` instead.

Comment: @SomethingDark I tried that but and it works to an extent, it doesn't seem to write any output to the text file like I want.

Comment: You need to enclose %username% in quotes if it has spaces. `cmd.exe /c net user "%username%" >priv.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Why You don't just use that %username% variable in your .bat file?
Just tested echo %username% returns current user name - seems no problem using it; if You have any exact case and reason why its not working - clarify case.
if you want to output to file use

```
echo %username% >> file.txt
net user %username% >> file.txt
```